# How To Use Where Clause & LIKE with Unicode Characters?

Tags: sql-server-2005, unicode, where-clause

I Have a table with column donor details and i am using following query to bind a grid in asp.net back end is sql server 2005.donordetails is a unicode column

```
select donordetails,serialno,did from sktdonor where donordetails  like N'% "+  DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text +" %' order by serialno asc
```

**THE QUERY GOT EXECUTED BUT IT SHOWS NO OUTPUT
PLEASE HELP !!!!**

Answer (score 0):

(A somewhat wild guess, but these things happen sometimes.) You've got spaces around the `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text` value. As a result, your query is looking for that value not merely as a substring of `donordetails` but as a separate word, more specifically, a word both preceded and followed by at least one space character. If that wasn't your intention then just remove the spaces (the one just after the leading `%` and the one before the final `%`).